# How to get model instance's attribute in UpdateView (Django)?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have an UpdateView for a model. I want to get the 'car_owner' attribute (of the Newcars model) in the UpdateView. Here's the code.

***models.py***

```
class Newcars(models.Model):
    shop_no = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0, related_name='newcars')
    car_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    car_owner = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('carapp:index')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.car_name + ' - ' +  self.car_owner
```

***views.py***
(Here's the UpdateView.)

```
class NewcarUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Newcars
    fields = ['car_name', 'car_owner']
```

***urls.py*** (only the necessary part of the urlpatterns)

```
url(r'^newcars/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.NewcarUpdate.as_view(), name='newcar-update'),
```

This is what I intend to do with the UpdateView, but cannot understand how.

```
class NewcarUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Newcars
    fields = ['car_name', 'car_owner']
    #Get the selected newcar object's 'car_owner' attribute.
    #Check if the object's 'car_owner' attribute == "sometext" or not.
    #If matches, only then go the normal update form.
    #If doesn't, redirect to a 404 page.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this method to your view:

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.get_object().car_owner != "sometext":
        raise Http404('Car owner does not match.')
    return super(NewcarUpdate, self).dispatch(
        request, *args, **kwargs)
```

You will need to import `Http404` from `django.http`

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Can you please describe in short the parameters of the dispatch()? I have read in the web, but can't understand clearly.

Comment: Sure, here's a quick explanation. Every view takes a request and returns a response. That's what `request` is. `args` is just a list of additional things that the view might need. `kwargs` is a dictionary of key, value mappings. you can print these variables out to see what's inside of them.

Comment: This was a lot simpler. Thanks.

Comment: @DoucheTholi `dispatch` is one of the first (maybe the first, I'm not sure) methods that happen when you use a class based view. It's a good place to check things like this.

Answer (score 1):

You could that in the [get_object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) method:

```
from django.http import Http404
# ...

class NewcarUpdate(UpdateView):
    # ...
    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = super(NewcarUpdate, self).get_object(queryset)
        if obj.car_owner == "sometext":
            raise Http404
        return obj
```

Comment: "must be type, not NewcarUpdate". Getting TypeError in line "obj = super(self, NewcarUpdate).get_object(queryset)"

Comment: `obj = super(self, NewcarUpdate).get_object(queryset)` should be `obj = super(NewcarUpdate, self).get_object(queryset)`